# Argmin with the Euclidean distance condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, euclidean-distance

In Python, I have a vector `v` of 300 elements and an array `arr` of 20k 300-dimensional vectors. How do I get quickly the indices of the `k` closest elements to `v` from the array `arr`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this task with `numpy`

```
import numpy as np
v = np.array([[1,1,1,1]])
arr = np.array([
  [1,1,1,1],
  [2,2,2,2],
  [3,3,3,3]
])
dist = np.linalg.norm(v - arr, axis=1) # Euclidean distance
min_distance_index = np.argmin(dist) # Find index of minimum distance
closest_vector = arr[min_distance_index] # Get vector having minimum distance
closest_vector
# array([1, 1, 1, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Since 300 is a very small number, sorting *all* elements and then just using the `k first is not an expensive operation (usually; it depends on how many thousand times  per second you need to do this).

so, `sorted()` is your friend; use the `key=` keyword argument, `sorted_vector = sorted(v ,key=…)`  to implement sorting by euclidean distance.

Then, use the classic `array[:end]` syntax to select the first `k`.